# How do I signal to a web server that I'm posting gzipped data?

Tags: json, http, gzip, content-type

I have a client that will be posting large JSON files to an API server. Since the files are so compressable, I would like to gzip them and send the compressed data.

What I would like to know is: What is the best way to signal my intent to the server?

Basically, I want the reverse of `Accept-encoding`, such that the server would treat the data as only compressed for transport purposes, and automatically decompress the data before interpreting it according to the `Content-Type`.

This means that I can't set the `Content-Type` field to `application/gzip` because it needs to be `application/json` for the server to understand what the true uncompressed data encoding is.

`Content-Transfer-Encoding` looks like it would serve my purposes, but it was built with email in mind, and only supports `7bit`, `quoted-printable`, `base64`, `8bit`, and `binary`.

Does transparent compression/decompression for HTTP transport from client to server exist? And if not, what are the best practices for what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "reverse" of the `Accept-encoding` header is `Content-encoding`. This signals to the server that the content is gzipped:

```
Content-encoding: gzip
```

You're correct that you shouldn't use the `Content-type` header for this, since the gzip compression is purely a matter of how the request is encoded, not what it represents.